# history doesn't display as sudo user

Tags: command-line, sudo

On a few of my ubuntu installations, when I run `sudo su` and become sudo user, I can type history and view a list of commands run as sudo user. However, on my one ubuntu installation, for some reason when I run `sudo su` and type `history`, I just get this:

```
$ sudo su
# history
1  history
```

But I know for certain that a lot of commands were run as sudo user, but when I ssh out and ssh back into my ubuntu server, they do not display, like how they do on the other servers. Do I have some switch or something disabled on this one server? How can I regain access to view the history of commands run as sudo user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some possibilities why you do not keep shell history:

- Your root shell is not `/bin/bash` but `/bin/sh` (symlinked to `/bin/dash`). Change this with the `chsh` command.
- The filesystem where `/root` resides is mounted read-only, so the history file cannot be written.
- The variable `HISTFILE` is set to a value other than `/root/.bash_history`. An empty file disables history, other values are used as location to write the history to.

Answer (score 9):

`history` is what's known as a builtin. It's essentially a bash function that operates within your session (like the rest of the logging that feeds `~/.bash_history` too).

When you run `sudo something`, that's happening within your session, not root's. Additionally, when something is run with sudo, it' doesn't spawn a separate bash session and then run the command. It's just executed with the correct privileges (I'm simplifying the truth somewhat).

This mildly undercuts Lekensteyn's different shell point. It's true, it just doesn't matter. Neither root `bash` or `dash` is the shell running the command. You can prove this by running something like `sudo -u $USER whoami` and then looking at `~/.bash_history`. There is only one command. If this were another shell, I would expect to see `sudo -u $USER whoami` followed by `whoami`.

Also `sudo su -c 'echo $0'` outputs the parent shell (`bash` in my case) though I'm not sure if this is as significant.

---

Anyway, when you run `sudo something` it just goes into your own `~/.bash_history`. If you want to see the command that you've run with `sudo`, run:

```
grep -E '^sudo' ~/.bash_history
```

Comment: Exactly! The commands run as _sudo_ are logged in the user's .bash_history i.e. /home/userName/.bash_history file and not in /root/.bash_history. Of course, if any commands were executed after sudo su or sudo -i, those would be logged in /root/.bash_history

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party here, but I figured out that if I do:

```
$ sudo su
$ cd ~
$ vi .bash_history
```

The root history does come up in this file on the root home folder